# tcolorbox is measuring the wrong height when a parbox follows

Tags: xetex, tcolorbox, parbox

Awhile back, I learned how to [measure the y coordinate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/336910/107497) in my pdf.  I've recently run into a combination of parbox, tcolorbox, and XeLaTeX that is giving me bad results.

In the following example, `\showheight{uniqueLabel}` prints its height in the page (after a second compilation).  "Mark 2" is the anomalous result, and seems to depend on what happens after that line.

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcounter{marks}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\showheight}[1]{%
 \stepcounter{marks}
 This line (mark \arabic{marks}) is
 \ifcsname myyloc#1\endcsname% 4718592 sp/in = 65536 sp/pt * 72 pt/in
  \the\numexpr10*\csname myyloc#1\endcsname/4718592\relax/10
 \else%
  ??
 \fi%
 inches from the bottom of the page
 %\strut
 \pdfsavepos%
 \write\@auxout{\protect\gdef\string\myyloc#1{\the\pdflastypos}}%
}
\makeatother
 

\begin{document}

\showheight{before} % mark 1

\begin{tcolorbox}
\showheight{inbox}\\ % mark 2
\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1-3]}% Mark 2 is 3.5 inches from the bottom
%\parbox{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1-3]} % Mark 2 is 6.1 inches from the bottom
%\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\lipsum[1-3]} % Mark 2 is 8.6 inches from the bottom
%\lipsum[1-3] % Mark 2 is 8.6 inches from the bottom
%\mbox{}\\[-\baselineskip] % fixes the measuring problem, causes underfull hbox
\end{tcolorbox}

\showheight{after} % mark 3

\end{document}
```

Shows that

[image: mark 2 has the wrong height]

(Why do I have a parbox inside of a tcolorbox?  For better or worse, because I was using some of the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9394/107497).)

How can I make sure that the y coordinate is correctly measured?  Or should I not be having a parbox within a tcolorbox?

Comment: with pdflatex it works. With the parbox the box has a large depth and this seems to confuse xelatex. You could add a \vspace{0pt} after the parbox.